# Disable/Enable context menu item depending on listview item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I have a `UserControl` with a `ListView` in it. 
In addition I have a class **listViewItems.cs** with a DisplayMemberBinding to a `GridView` in `listView`.

Each ListView-Item has a context-menu.
Now I'm trying to enable/disable the context-menu-items depending if a value in class ListViewItems is `null`

I've tried a binding to the `IsEnabled` property to the boolean value `ShowResItemEn` in class **ListViewItems.cs** but it does not work.

DataOutput.xaml

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Name="cmListView" x:Key="ItemContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"> 
        <MenuItem x:Name="itmRes"
                    Header="Reservierungen anzeigen"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem.ShowResItemEn, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                    Command="{Binding ShowResItemCmd}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" >
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</ListView.Resources>
```

class ListViewItems.cs

```
public Boolean ShowResItemEn
{
   get
   {
       return (auftrNr[0] == null) ? false : true; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have your context menu in the items or in the listview?

Comment: I edited my question, its defined as ListView Resource

Comment: You have included both too much code and not enough. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your question. Explain in precise detail what that code does now and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Ok I edited my question now. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it works now. I've setted the AncestorType wrong

```
IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=SelectedItem.ShowBesItemEn}"
```